# How do you execute a procedure or function using Oracle PL/SQL and the HTP/HTF packages

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm working on creating a web app using Oracle's PL/SQL. My main goal is to write a front end HTML/CSS interface and then have PL/SQL do the heavy lifting with respect to handling the inputs but the users. This is meant to be an exercise in PL/SQL and PL/SQL web development.

I've been able to determine how to get PL/SQL to write the oracle to a file but now I'm unsure of how to get my input areas (forms, buttons, anchors, etc) to work.

```
  Create or replace package body web_plsql as
  procedure hello is
  begin
    htp.p('Hello World!');
  end hello;
end web_plsql;
/

EXEC DBMS_EPG.CREATE_DAD('WEBTEST', '/webtest/*');
EXEC DBMS_EPG.SET_DAD_ATTRIBUTE('WEBTEST', 'database-username', 'ACARNES');
EXEC DBMS_EPG.AUTHORIZE_DAD('WEBTEST', 'HR');

/
```

This code will write the HTML.

The next thing is I understand I need to create a DAD (Database Access Descriptor) but what I'm struggling with is the connection between my PL/SQL and the connection to the webpage. In the picture below I don't understand the web server connection steps. Does anyone have any guidance around this? 
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind, what is the purpose of building a PL/SQL backend? Just as an exercise, or is there any other interesting benefit in it?

Comment: Correct, it's simply an exercise. Great question though!

Comment: It seems the missing part of your solution is the web gateway to allow end users to access your application. Try this on for size: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_web.htm#g1026380

Comment: Thank you for that addition, I've been reading through the documentation and I just don't understand how to make the connection, can you elaborate on what I need to do?